# Trying to install opencv using homebrew. ERROR: modules/highgui/CMakeFiles/opencv_highgui.dir/all Error 2

Tags: macos, opencv

I have mac, os x 10.8.3

I used to have macports installed, I deleted it and trying to install opencv using Homebrew.

I installed lame, ffmpeg. Changed $PATH. The error is still the same:

```
Nellys-MacBook-Pro:~ nellysmitt$ brew install opencv
==> Downloading http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/opencv-unix/
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/opencv-2.4.5.tar.gz
==> cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/2.4.5 -DCMAKE_BUILD_TY
==> make
[ 38%] Building CXX object modules/highgui/CMakeFiles/opencv_highgui.dir/src/grfmt_tiff.cpp.o
Linking CXX shared library ../../lib/libopencv_video.dylib
[ 38%] Built target opencv_video
make[1]: *** [modules/highgui/CMakeFiles/opencv_highgui.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2

READ THIS: https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/troubleshooting
```

Brew doctor was ok before installing ffmpeg. NOw it tells:

```
Nellys-MacBook-Pro:~ nellysmitt$ brew doctor
Warning: Unbrewed dylibs were found in /usr/local/lib.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected dylibs:
    /usr/local/lib/libavcodec.52.108.0.dylib
    /usr/local/lib/libavcore.0.16.1.dylib
    /usr/local/lib/libavdevice.52.2.3.dylib
    /usr/local/lib/libavfilter.1.74.0.dylib
    /usr/local/lib/libavformat.52.93.0.dylib
    /usr/local/lib/libavutil.50.36.0.dylib
    /usr/local/lib/libmp3lame.0.dylib
    /usr/local/lib/libswscale.0.12.0.dylib

Warning: Unbrewed .la files were found in /usr/local/lib.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected .la files:
    /usr/local/lib/libmp3lame.la

Warning: Unbrewed .pc files were found in /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected .pc files:
    /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/libavcodec.pc
    /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/libavcore.pc
    /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/libavdevice.pc
    /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/libavfilter.pc
    /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/libavformat.pc
    /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/libavutil.pc
    /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/libswscale.pc

Warning: Unbrewed static libraries were found in /usr/local/lib.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected static libraries:
    /usr/local/lib/libavcodec.a
    /usr/local/lib/libavcore.a
    /usr/local/lib/libavdevice.a
    /usr/local/lib/libavfilter.a
    /usr/local/lib/libavformat.a
    /usr/local/lib/libavutil.a
    /usr/local/lib/libmp3lame.a
    /usr/local/lib/libswscale.a
```

But the ERROR is the SAME for the last 24 hours. I'm mad and desperate. Don't know how to install this damn OpenCV.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me Oct 2013:

first **brew update** to be sure homebrew is current
then **brew doctor** and be sure homebrew reports no issues

Then, **brew tap homebrew/science** to point to latest opencv

Then **brew install opencv**

Best of luck!