# Error installing OpenCV: Error 1, 2

Tags: macos, opencv

I am attempting to install OpenCv on my Mac Pro (and I have already succesfully installed it on my Macbook), however I am getting an error message when doing

```
sudo make install
```

in the directory I am striving to install it in. I am running Snow Leopard (10.6.8) and have Xcode (as well as MacPorts) installed. My question is similar to this one (which is  unanswered as of today): [Trying to install opencv using homebrew. ERROR: modules/highgui/CMakeFiles/opencv_highgui.dir/all Error 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16365549/trying-to-install-opencv-using-homebrew-error-modules-highgui-cmakefiles-openc)

The following is the error message:

```
[ 67%] Building CXX object modules/ocl/CMakeFiles/opencv_ocl.dir/src/error.cpp.o
/Users/maxweissenbacher/Documents/OpenCV/opencv-2.4.5/modules/ocl/src/error.cpp:  
In function ‘const char* cv::ocl::getOpenCLErrorString(int)’:
/Users/maxweissenbacher/Documents/OpenCV/opencv-2.4.5/modules/ocl/src/error.cpp:82:  
error: ‘CL_MISALIGNED_SUB_BUFFER_OFFSET’ was not declared in this scope
/Users/maxweissenbacher/Documents/OpenCV/opencv-2.4.5/modules/ocl/src/error.cpp:84:  
error: ‘CL_EXEC_STATUS_ERROR_FOR_EVENTS_IN_WAIT_LIST’ was not declared in this scope
make[2]: *** [modules/ocl/CMakeFiles/opencv_ocl.dir/src/error.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [modules/ocl/CMakeFiles/opencv_ocl.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I appreciate any help.

Thanks in advance,
Max.

Comment: Have you perchance tried installing with Homebrew?

Comment: No I haven't but I will and post again when I have results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you can't install it on Snow Leopard, at least without some additional manipulations with sources.The reason is OpenCL version. 
Take a look at [this thread](http://mac-os-forge.2317878.n4.nabble.com/MacPorts-37339-OpenCV-2-4-3-debug-eigen-opencl-openni-python27-universal-fails-to-build-td202594.html) for additional info

Comment: Thanks for the tip, that solves the mystery. A pity Apple doesn't allow PowerPC programs (like Shake) to work with Mountain Lion. Anyone know if both OpenCV and PowerPC programs work with Lion (according to this Wiki page: [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mac_OS_X_Lion#Software_incompatibilities), they don't)?

Comment: @Max Since Lion PPC apps are no longer supported as far as I know